# Radiobutton within the Popover not be checked via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, frameworks

I have a query where fill an html table with the records from the database. In one of the columns of each row, there are some options how to edit, delete, add photos and another option that opens the Popover.

This Popover is Bootstrap 3, when I open the popover any line shows 3 radiobuttons and their onclick run a script in the database without refreshing the page. I want the selected radio be checked without having to refresh the page, but I'm not getting.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Follow the code:

```
<td class="col-small center">
<div class="action-buttons">                                    
<a class="popover-dw" href="#" data-popover="true">
  <i class="fa fa-cog bigger-130" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
</a>
<div class="popover-content" style="display:none">
  <form class="marcarComoVendidoAlugado">
    <div>
      <p>
        Anúncio: <%=rsAnuncios("id")%>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input <%=checkNone%> type="radio" name="vendidoAlugado" id="none<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>" onclick="alugadoVendido('src/rotinas/rotinas.asp?acao=Vendido&id=<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>&tipo=none&idInput=none<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>', 'none<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>');" /> NENHUM
      </p>
      <p>
        <input <%=checkVendido%> type="radio" name="vendidoAlugado" id="marcarComoVendido<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>" onclick="alugadoVendido('src/rotinas/rotinas.asp?acao=Vendido&id=<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>&tipo=vendido&idInput=marcarComoVendido<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>', 'marcarComoVendido<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>');" /> Marcar anúncio como VENDIDO
      </p>
      <p>
        <input <%=checkAlugado%> type="radio" name="vendidoAlugado" id="marcarComoAlugado<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>" onclick="alugadoVendido('src/rotinas/rotinas.asp?acao=Vendido&id=<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>&tipo=alugado&idInput=marcarComoAlugado<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>', 'marcarComoAlugado<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>');" /> Marcar anúncio como ALUGADO
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>  
</div>
</td>
```

And here javascript:

```
function alugadoVendido(url, obj1){
    //$(".marcarComoVendidoAlugado").attr("checked", false);
    $(".marcarComoVendidoAlugado").prop("checked", false);
    $("#"+obj1).prop("checked", true);
    window.rotinas.location.href = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to make the page go to another page with the command `window.rotinas.location.href = url;`.

You have to use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to avoid making the browser go to another page. jQuery has an excellent AJAX framework that you can use. Read about it here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

A simple example with your application.

```
function alugadoVendido(url, obj1){
    $(".marcarComoVendidoAlugado").prop("checked", false);
    $("#"+obj1).prop("checked", true);
    $.ajax({
        url: url
    });
}
```

Even simpler with `$.get`.

```
function alugadoVendido(url, obj1){
    $(".marcarComoVendidoAlugado").prop("checked", false);
    $("#"+obj1).prop("checked", true);
    $.get(url);
}
```

Since these examples above don't contain any function callbacks you can't verify that the server has received the response. To do this you can do as follows.

```
function alugadoVendido(url, obj1){
    $(".marcarComoVendidoAlugado").prop("checked", false);
    $("#"+obj1).prop("checked", true);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function() {
            // Successfully sent the data to the server.
        },
        error: function() {
            // Failed sending the data to the server.
        }
    });
}
```

I would recommend looking into REST and use POST or PUT instead but your server is probably configured to receive GET requests.

To send a request as a POST do as follows.

```
function alugadoVendido(url, obj1){
    $(".marcarComoVendidoAlugado").prop("checked", false);
    $("#"+obj1).prop("checked", true);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        success: function() {
            // Successfully sent the data to the server.
        },
        error: function() {
            // Failed sending the data to the server.
        }
    });
}
```

You should rewrite your `onclick` to send the query as an object to the function instead so that the data can be sent correctly like POST want it, like this:

```
onclick="alugadoVendido('src/rotinas/rotinas.asp', {acao: 'Vendido', id: '<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>', tipo: 'none', idInput: 'none<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>'}, 'none<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>');"
```

Then the JavaScript can be:

```
function alugadoVendido(url, data, obj1){
    $(".marcarComoVendidoAlugado").prop("checked", false);
    $("#"+obj1).prop("checked", true);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function() {
            // Successfully sent the data to the server.
        },
        error: function() {
            // Failed sending the data to the server.
        }
    });
}
```